# The iframe stopped when hidden

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, vue.js

I'm writing a live video website, which use a third-party tools to play the video.

To simplify my problem, I embedded all the live video components into a single HTML page. It looks like this.

```html
<iframe data-v-140cfad2="" width="800" height="500" src="/backend/render/live?uid=047a911d83&amp;vid=254084" id="haha"></iframe>
```

When the page was loaded, it played video normally. However, I write following commands in Chrome console.

```
a = document.getElementById('haha')
a.hidden = true;//or a.style.display = 'none'
```

Not only the video window disappeared (as I wish), the audio disappeared (that is not I want). I don't know how It stopped, and if there is any way can still run the video in the background.

---

Update :

Change the size of iframe into 0px * 0px is a way to move the iframe into background. However it does not fit my situation.

I was using vue.js & element-ui. The iframe was inside a `el-tabs` components, which means all the hidden operations was automatically done after the tab change. I don't know how to prevent such default operation.

[image: A demo of my project]

---

Backend iframe code :

```js
(() => {
        window.onload = function() {
                let ctx = document.getElementById('player');
                let uid = ctx.getAttribute('uid');
                let vid = ctx.getAttribute('vid');
                let cfg = {
                        uid: uid,
                        vid: vid,
                        height: 500,
                        width: 800,
                };
                console.log(">>>",cfg);
                player = polyvObject('#player').
                        livePlayer(cfg);
        }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://player.polyv.net/script/player.js"></script>
  <script src="http://player.polyv.net/livescript/liveplayer.js"></script>
  <script src="/backend/js/live.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/backend/css/live.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="player" uid="#{uid}" vid="#{vid}"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

This bug will not happen when `iframe` embed a MP4 file, or a normal web page. Only happens on my own page. (that strange, because I don't understand how the functions INSIDE the `iframe` was trigger by the hidden style OUTSIDE `iframe`).

I solve this problem by modifying the `element-ui` components to avoid using `v-show` when hiding components. Details show in the solution posted by myself.

Thanks for all people answering my problem :)

Comment: You could position the video offscreen, or set its opacity to zero, or set `visibility` instead of `display`.  But are you sure you want to keep audio autoplaying while hiding the controls that allow the user to stop that audio?  That's going to drive a lot of users away from your site...

Comment: As I mentioned in the update, I have a menu bar contains several different components. The video is one of them, the rest of them are something like chatting area or dashboard. I want user to switch between them without closing the video.

Comment: That's a completely different question, then, since it depends on how the element-ui tabs component handles its inactive tabs -- if they're not being drawn into the DOM at all, which is possible, you may need to use a different mechanism that hides them with `v-show` instead of `v-if` for example.  (I don't know if element-ui supports this or if you'd need to modify or re-implement it.)

Comment: I am now quit sure it is caused by the code in the third-party package inside `iframe`. Because neither the video nor the embedded web page in the iframe have such bug. But still figuring how the hidden operation outside the `iframe` triggers functions inside the `iframe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I solve my own problem by an ugly approach.

The iframe works fine when style `visibility='hidden'` was set. So I just rewrite the `el-tab-pane` in the element-ui.

The initial version of `el-tab-pane` was:

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="el-tab-pane"
    v-if="(!lazy || loaded) || active"
    v-show="active"
    role="tabpanel"
    :aria-hidden="!active"
    :id="`pane-${paneName}`"
    :aria-labelledby="`tab-${paneName}`"
  >
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

A did a little modification as follow (the v-visible was contained by [npm vue-visible package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-visible)) [`TabPane`]

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="el-tab-pane"
    v-if="(!lazy || loaded) || active"
    v-show="active || fly"
    v-visible="active || !fly"
    role="tabpanel"
    :aria-hidden="!active"
    :id="`pane-${paneName}`"
    :aria-labelledby="`tab-${paneName}`"
  >
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

In my own code, I replaced the `el-tab-pane` to my DIY `TabPane`, adding a `props` named `fly` to indicate whether to use `v-show` or the `v-visible` to hide the components.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the iFrame

```
.hiddeniFrame{
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
}
```

Or move it away off the screen

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but as I mentioned in the new update. This is not quite implementable in my project. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Maybe apply position:fixed before tabChange to take the iFrame out of the Tabs , and when focusing on the tab return to the original position ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be backend issue, so it will be great to update question with iframe content. I've reproduce your situation audio still playing after hiding iframe

```js
setTimeout(() => { document.getElementById('test').hidden = true; }, 10000 )
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.instagram.com/p/Bn5ar2uBd2C/embed/" width="640" height="880" id="test"></iframe>
```

Comment: If I change the src into a normal video link, it works! But... I don't get that is there any difference between embedding a normal video or a web page  inside an iframe.

Comment: @TobyMao i've updated code with embeded variant. Still works. Just start video manually before hiding in 10 secs. Btw may be manual start is a caus of work?